# PHP - updating sql data

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, sql-update

i'm new to php and i have this php script, but for some reason its not working. What i want is when the checkbox is checked, the value of the specific table will increase by 1 after i click the 'submit' button.

php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
$sql = "UPDATE users SET marks = marks + 2 WHERE id = $selected";
mysqli_query($sql);
}
}
}
?>
```

and here is my table code which collect the data:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <table class='default'>
    <tr>
        <th>Delete</th><th>Username</th><th>Email</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Join Date</th><th>Last Sign In</th><th>Logins</th>
    </tr>
        <tbody>

<?php foreach ($userData as $v1) { ?>

            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?=$v1->id?>" /></td>
            <td><?=$v1->username?></td>
            <td><?=$v1->fname?></td>
            <td><?=$v1->lname?></td>
            <td><?=$v1->marks?></td>
            <td><?=$v1->join_date?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

where am i doing wrong?

Comment: can you please specify the error/output?

Comment: Without knowing what's actually happening, it's hard to help

Comment: Please read this article about MySQL injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php Also, don't use if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ Some browsers do filter the submit button out. use if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) { Also, don't use <?=$var?> this can cause problems when migrating to other servers/hosting. use <?php echo $var; ?> instead.

Comment: @Scriptman What sort of problems would `<?= ?>` cause?

Comment: @apokryfos, That is called PHP Shorttags and can be disabled in server configuration (php.ini, "short_open_tags") There is a possibility that shorttags will be removed in the future.

Comment: `short_open_tags`  doesn't affect the `<?= ?>` tags since version 5.4, and I don't think not using something on the off-chance of it being removed in the future is a good approach since you'll end up not using anything.

Comment: @Riddhi Rathod
There's no error or any message shown. When i clicked the submit button, the page just refresh and the value is not updated.

UPDATE: Here is the error:
 Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/u523029837/public_html/marks.php on line 106:

`mysqli_query($sql);`